# TestNG framework containing testng.xml has parameter tag whether it will work on AWS?

Tags: android, xml, selenium, amazon-web-services, testng

AM putting testng.xml file in the root directory like test.jar >>testng.xml, but while running the testcase in AWS Device farm always throws following error.

testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="testing" thread-count="1" parallel="tests">
    <parameter name="deviceConfigFileName" value="config/Config.xlsx">
    </parameter><test name="test1">
    <parameter name="devicesToRun" value="Device1"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="script.ScriptRunner"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

---

```
Parameter 'deviceConfigFileName' is required by @Configuration on method setup but has not been marked @Optional or defined
[TestNG] 
[TestNG] at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:155)
[TestNG] at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:358)
[TestNG] at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:86)
[TestNG] at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:199)
[TestNG] at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
[TestNG] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
[TestNG] at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
[TestNG] at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
[TestNG] at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.r...(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
[TestNG] at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
[TestNG] at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
[TestNG] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
[TestNG] at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
[TestNG] at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
```

Any one help me where to put testng.xml file on zip with debendency file

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

Seems like you are trying to pass a parameter which will tell where you .xlsx files is located.

Unfortunately, the support for testng parameters through testng.xml in currently not in place. This is something which is on our backlog and will be looked at soon.

Meanwhile if you are looking to get the xlsx file to be picked up here are two ways I would suggest going about it:

1. Make sure the excel file is placed under src/test/resources/com/yourexcelfile.xlsx/csv
2. This will place the file in the test jar file under com folder.
3. Once that is confirmed you should be able to read the file using one of the two code snippets below:

   java.net.URL resource =    ClassLoader.getSystemResource(“/com/yourexcelfile.xlsx");

   File file = new File(resource.toURI());

   FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

OR

If you are using Apache POI APIs for reading excel files:

```
  InputStream ins = getClass().getResourceAsStream(“/com/yourexcelfile.xlsx”);
  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ins);
  sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
  ins.close();
```

Comment: Thanks you. My frame work looks to execute multiple test case on simply passing parameter in testng.xml.

Comment: If i put testcases under resource folder i need to add n no of @Test methods. Is other any way to execute n of test cases with only one Test method.

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand putting the test cases under resources folder?
If you want just one method to trigger all your tests how do you get reports for each test locally? 
You can have all the test methods get called from one test method but this will cause it to not report those tests separately in device farm. It will show the result of only the main test that calls all the other tests.

Comment: Putting testcases under resource folder -> multiple testcases excel sheets under resource folder. I have writing each step status(pass/fail) to appropriate excel sheet on local machine same thing expecting in device farm.

Comment: Are you able to read the excel file or are you getting File not found exception?

Comment: Any updates on when will this be supported, @NikofTime ? It's been a little over half a year.

Comment: @Mig82: This feature is not in place yet but I have made a note for it from your feedback as it helps shape our backlog.